# How to get EST midnight timestamp from ZonedDateTime

Tags: java

I need the EST midnight timstamp using the `ZonedDateTime`.
It should look like in this format `2019-04-16 00:00:00`
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDate::atStartOfDay`

`EST` is not a time zone. Avoid the 2-4 character pseudo-zones. A real time zone has a name in `Continent/Region`. Perhaps you meant a zone such as `America/New_York` or `America/Montreal`.

Let `LocalDate` determine the first moment. Some days in some zones do not begin at 00:00:00, but may start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(z);
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay(z);
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace("T" ," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestTime{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(date);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localDate = date.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(localDate.format(formatter));
    }
}
```